# RBioFormats library needs internet connection to load

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I'm using RBioFormats for image processing purposes with R. I'm not able to load RBioFormats library when my computer has not internet connection.
R's console throught the error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RbioFormats':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RBioFormats', details:
 call: NULL
 error: failed to download Bio-Formats Java library
 Check your internet connection
```

I'm using GNU/Linux OS. Firstly, I thought it was due to the version 11 of java environment installed. I've noticed the v11 is a develper version. After installing java environment v8, result in the same error output. The result is that I cannot use RBioFormats library when I have not internet connection.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Anarchy Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8      
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8          LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8           LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RBioFormats_0.0.54 rJava_0.9-11      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1          locfit_1.5-9.1      lattice_0.20-38     png_0.1-7           fftwtools_0.9-8     digest_0.6.19       bitops_1.0-6        tiff_0.1-5         
 [9] grid_3.6.0          EBImage_4.26.0      tools_3.6.0         htmlwidgets_1.3     RCurl_1.95-4.12     jpeg_0.1-8          abind_1.4-5         parallel_3.6.0     
[17] compiler_3.6.0      BiocGenerics_0.30.0 htmltools_0.3.6
```

Comment: The error message says “failed to download Bio-Formats Java library”. It looks like it needs to download the library every time you run it? You probably need to configure the R package to know where your local copy of BioFormats is installed.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I cannot see how to configure it. Some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RBioFormats version 0.057, is not required Internet connection on startup anymore. [Link to commit](https://github.com/aoles/RBioFormats/commit/c87bba132a9d7e162cf1bc8df0b716ce37f3e11e)